# How to remove background rectangle?

Tags: android, android-layout

![Hi I am using rectangle and give radius but still there is a white rectangle behind corners, so how can I remove this.? The code is given below. Code for ListView:`<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp" >
    </ListView>` And code for row_memo:`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_edit1"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:onClick="editMemoData"
        android:src="@drawable/edtsrclkup_wiz" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_delete"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:onClick="deleteMemo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_memo_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="Memo Content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDy75.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set Background of list view as transparent.